# Hit multiple pages on multiple domains to activate PHP script, can't use cron?

Tags: php, .htaccess, cron, cpanel

I need to run a PHP script once a day. I thought about using Cron Jobs, but I believe that's set up on the *domain* level.

I've got dozens of domains I need to check. and hundred of subdomains. The URL structures look like this:

```
client-one.siteone.com         // First Installation
client-two.siteone.com         //       ''
client-one.sitetwo.com         // Second Installation
client-two.sitetwo.com         //       ''
someclient.somesite.com        // Third Installation
anotherclient.anothersite.com  // Fourth Insallation
```

and we have one setup that's directories instead of domains:

```
domain.com/client-one          // Fifth Installation
domain.com/client-two          //       ''
```

The PHP Script will all be located at essentially the same location, `client.mysite.com/php-script.php` and `domain.com/client/php-script`

All of these domains and installations are on the same server, and will remain as such. I just need a way to cycle through all the `php-script.php`'s once every day, timing isn't important.

I can't figure out how to run "server-wide" cron jobs though, is there an alternative? External Service maybe? I'd rather not use another service, but I will if it's all but necessary.

Comment: Why don't you make 1 php file that will access all the other php files and cron that one file. Then you can check within your code if the request came from your server IP if not exit if it came then proceed with all the work they have to do.

Comment: That could work, I was hoping for something that would access all the sites on the server (it's reserved almost exclusively for this application). I'd like to avoid having to manually include new sites, but I guess it's not a huge deal if that's how it has to be

Comment: Another option perhaps [**Go**](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/go/config/cron). Yes, you would have to have a list to loop thru to access everything but not a big deal. If the server is yours then you could make a simple bash script to run.